# How to see ABI of android static library?

Tags: android, ios, architecture, static-libraries, abi

Is there any way of inspecting **static library  for android**? For example for iOS static libraries we can simply call :

```
lipo -info mylib.a
```

and it will display the architectures of `mylib.a` library. If there any similar way for android static library to see the **ABIs** of the library? If I run `lipo -info` on android static library I get error.

Any similar command? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 7):

I can think of two methods based on what is available on your host machine.

1. Use `objdump`. Something like `objdump -x somelib.a | grep arch`

*Expected output*: architecture: < arch name>

2. Use `readelf`. Something like `readelf -h somelib.a | grep Class`

*Expected output*: Class:                             <32/64 bit etc>

Comment: just to mention, this is giving the 32/64 bit and also the machine(arm, intel): 
`readelf -h somelib.a | grep 'Class\|File\|Machine'`